# Querydsl join condition

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I'm using querydsl with Spring JPA. I want to find entities that has a subitem with two conditions. This code works with a single condition (i.e. any.selected.isTrue()). However they do not work together. How can such a query be expressed using querydsl?

```
QSub any = exp.sub.any();
    builder.and(
        any.selected.isTrue().and(any.sub.person.id.eq(user.getId()))));
```

where builder is a boolean builder.

Comment: Please explain what's `exp` and what you want to obtain with `exp.sub.any()`.

Comment: @vmaldosan Thanks for your reply. Exp is my main entity i.e. auto exp = QMain.main. However I've found a solution which I will post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that (as suggested by other posts) creating a subquery solved the problem:

```
JPQLQuery<Tuple> where = JPAExpressions.select().from(QSub.sub).where(QSub.sub.id.eq(QMain.main.id), QSub.sub.selected.isTrue(), QSub.sub.userId.eq(user.getId()));
```

"Where" can then be added to the boolean builder as a condition.